# tcpdump not capturing any packets

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

I'm trying to monitor what's going on in my network, so I've tried `tcpdump` command. I'm just learning to use it, so I thought on playing around a little bit with it.

**My problem is that I cannot capture any packet using just tcpdump without any parameters.**

when I type `tcpdump`, I get this answer:

> tcpdump: packet printing is not supported for link type
>   BLUETOOTH_HCI_H4_WITH_PHDR: use -w

So I tried tcpdump: `tcpdump -w archivito` And I've got this:

> listening on bluetooth0, link-type BLUETOOTH_HCI_H4_WITH_PHDR
>   (Bluetooth HCI UART transport layer plus pseudo-header),
>
> capture size 65535 bytes
>
> 0 packets captured
>
> 62 packets received by filter
>
> 0 packets dropped by kernel

So the archivito file was empty, so I've tried: `tcpdump port 80` And I've got this reply:

> tcpdump: Bluetooth link-layer type filtering not implemented

How may I get some output from tcpdump? I've read the man pages about this command, but couldn't understand why it's not working for me.

So, I then tried `sudo tcpdump -w archivito`, and I've got this output:

> tcpdump: WARNING: eth0: no IPv4 address assigned tcpdump: listening on
>   eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes

It remains there for a while, but all I still get is

> 0 packets captured
>
> 0 packets received by filter
>
> 0 packets dropped by kernel

**Finally I tried `sudo tcpdump -i any`, and it worked (it captured several packets). But why it worked ONLY when asking it to monitor in all interfaces?**

Comment: What does `tcpdump -L` print?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the `tcpdump` man page:

```
   -i     Listen  on  interface.   If  unspecified, tcpdump searches the system interface list for the lowest numbered, configured up interface (excluding loop‐
          back), which may turn out to be, for example, ``eth0''.

          On Linux systems with 2.2 or later kernels, an interface argument of ``any'' can be used to capture packets from all interfaces.  Note  that  captures
          on the ``any'' device will not be done in promiscuous mode.
```

So, looking at your output, seems that the first available interface is `bluetooth0` which does not allow packet printing, and thus the error.

However, if specifying the `-i` flag to `any`, you're picking up any available interface that allows packet printing and that's why it works in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not in front of it right now but

there is a switch for tcpdump to list all interfaces, then you can specify specifically the one you want. Try `tcpdump --list-interfaces`  then you can do e.g. `tcpdump -i eth0` or whatever particular interface you want to listen on.